# Google cloud run terminates on signal 9

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a google cloud run instance with min=max=1 and cpu always allocated in order to keep alive the instance all the time.
This instance is not supposed to receive http requests. I use this instance to run tasks all the time in the background. Specifically i use laravel horizon and i have scheduled tasks that run every X minutes.

The problem is that every 3 days the container restarts. I basically terminates first with the following message

[image]

The logs following this message are

```
WARNING 2023-12-31T23:09:56.226021579Z Container terminated on signal 9.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:56.227556Z 2023-12-31 23:09:55 Running ['artisan' command:execute] in background
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:57.858518Z [s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:58.094845Z [s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:58.101377Z [fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:58.114547Z [fix-attrs.d] done.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:58.117210Z [cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:58.121936Z [cont-init.d] done.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:58.125717Z [services.d] starting services
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:58.177808Z [services.d] done.
INFO 2023-12-31T23:09:58.275042Z Default STARTUP TCP probe succeeded after 1 attempt for container "horizon-1" on port 8080.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:58.892058Z [31-Dec-2023 23:09:58] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 201
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:58.892081Z [31-Dec-2023 23:09:58] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.115109Z /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/supervisor/options.py:474: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.115120Z self.warnings.warn(
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.124359Z 2023-12-31 23:09:59,124 CRIT Supervisor is running as root. Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file. If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.124446Z 2023-12-31 23:09:59,124 WARN For [program:laravel-schedule], AUTO logging used for stderr_logfile without rollover, set maxbytes > 0 to avoid filling up filesystem unintentionally
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.124630Z 2023-12-31 23:09:59,124 WARN For [program:horizon-run], AUTO logging used for stderr_logfile without rollover, set maxbytes > 0 to avoid filling up filesystem unintentionally
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.125276Z 2023-12-31 23:09:59,124 CRIT Supervisor is running as root. Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file. If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.125681Z 2023-12-31 23:09:59,124 WARN For [program:laravel-schedule], AUTO logging used for stderr_logfile without rollover, set maxbytes > 0 to avoid filling up filesystem unintentionally
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.125689Z 2023-12-31 23:09:59,124 WARN For [program:horizon-run], AUTO logging used for stderr_logfile without rollover, set maxbytes > 0 to avoid filling up filesystem unintentionally
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.138177Z 2023-12-31 23:09:59,138 INFO supervisord started with pid 207
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:09:59.138395Z 2023-12-31 23:09:59,138 INFO supervisord started with pid 207
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:00.158832Z 2023-12-31 23:10:00,155 INFO spawned: 'laravel-schedule_00' with pid 223
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:00.159361Z 2023-12-31 23:10:00,155 INFO spawned: 'laravel-schedule_00' with pid 223
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:00.205530Z 2023-12-31 23:10:00,204 INFO spawned: 'horizon-run' with pid 225
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:00.206011Z 2023-12-31 23:10:00,204 INFO spawned: 'horizon-run' with pid 225
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:01.116437Z 2023-12-31 23:10:01 Running ['artisan' command:name] Horizon started successfully.
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:01.504652Z ............ 455ms2023-12-31 23:10:01,504 INFO success: laravel-schedule_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:01.505008Z 2023-12-31 23:10:01,504 INFO success: horizon-run entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:01.505060Z 2023-12-31 23:10:01,504 INFO success: laravel-schedule_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:01.505331Z DONE
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:01.505690Z 2023-12-31 23:10:01,504 INFO success: horizon-run entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
DEFAULT 2023-12-31T23:10:01.516709Z ⇂ Command description
```

After those messages it start working again.

Below you can see the screenshots from the metrics

[image]

[image]

For a reference, the message that the container terminated was logged at `2024-01-01 00:09:56` and at that time based on the metrics there is no high cpu or memory usage.

Comment: Part 1: Signal 9 is `SIGKILL`. That signal (interrupt) will abruptly terminate your container instance. That can happen with out-of-memory problems, but I do not see that in your logs. Note: containers do not run forever. Google can shut down or restart your container at any time.

Comment: Part 2:  ***Under normal circumstances, Cloud Run never stops a container that is handling requests. However, a container can stop suddenly in two cases: if your application exits (for instance due to an error in your application code) or if the container exceeds the memory limit.*** [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/lifecycle-container-cloud-run)

Comment: Part 3: What are the log entries before signal 9? Was the container idle for a long time or processing requests? As a test, try enabling `CPU Always Allocated` https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation

Comment: Usually processes only get a `KILL` signal after they've ignored a `TERM`inate signal. `TERM` is the OS politely asking the app to shut itself down, and `KILL` will never actually be seen by the app as the OS simply terminates the process. You should make sure that whatever is PID1 in your container can catch and handle a `TERM`, which will also better indicate the time at which the stop was first requested and under what conditions.

Comment: @Sammitch - That would apply to Linux (POSIX) operating systems, but not to Cloud Run which runs under gVisor and Borg. AFAIK: You cannot trap that signal within a Cloud Run instance. Do you have more information on this for Google Cloud Run?

Comment: In this case the instance does not receive any requests at all. As you can see in the metrics, the requests count is 0 all the time and even though it is 0, the instance keeps running and executing background tasks for 3 days. After 3 days it restarts, and it keeps running again for 3 days and that is how it goes. Before the "terminate" message the logs are the normal logs from the background tasks that are executed. There is no "term" or "kill" message

Comment: Could it be that this is just how cloud-run works internally ? Meaning even though the instances min=max=1 and cpu always allocated, it will still terminate after some point ?

Comment: i think i saw somewhere that with min=max=1 and cpu always allocated the instance is supposed to run all the time and not scale to 0. if i'm not wrong it was said by @guillaume-blaquiere

Comment: OK, those details provide the probable solution. When a Cloud Run instance is processing requests, it receives CPU time, otherwise, Google can and will throttle the CPU allocation to zero. Google only bills you for request time, so you will not get free CPU by using background threads. Background threads that do not receive CPU time can fail. Enable `CPU Always Allocated` and test the results of that change.

Comment: As I mentioned, Google can terminate/restart a container at any time. If you have background threads and your container is not constantly busy processing HTTP requests, then you should enable the CPU to be running so that background requests will receive CPU allocation. Either that or select a service such as Compute Engine.

Comment: The `CPU Always Allocated` is already enabled. Do you mean that even if `CPU Always Allocated` is enabled, the instance still needs to receive http requests in order to stay alive ?

Comment: I found the post that says with `min_instance=1` and `CPU Always Allocated` , cloud run instance can stay alive . https://stackoverflow.com/a/70985995/12956338

Comment: Just to clarify, the configuration is `Minimum number of instances=Maximum number of instances=1` and `CPU Always Allocated` is enabled. With this configuration i get `Signal 9` every 3 days with 0 HTTP requests

Comment: Cloud Run is a serverless service designed to process query. In addition, as any serverless service, Google is able to shutdown instance and to replace it by another one (for technical reason, outage, updates,...). Min instance guarantee you will have 1, at least. At a point of time, you can have 2 (or more) simultaneously. Cloud run Autoscaller choose by itself, it's serverless = server managed by Google!

Comment: If you have CPU always allocated, then your background threads are allocated CPU time even with no HTTP requests. However, Google can restart your container at any time so you must design for that. I am not sure why Google is restarting your instance every 72 hours but the answer really does not matter. You must design for that.

Comment: That being said, you have an issue because your application design is wrong. You use Cloud Run as a VM, but it is not! Cloud Run is designed to serve HTTP request. If you have a cron running in background, use something else: Cloud Scheduler is great for that. Or Cloud Run Jobs (max 24h per job execution) or Cloud Batch. But do not use request-response service to run batch processes.

Comment: @JohnHanley, 72h (3 days) sounds "fine". App Engine instances are, at least, restarted every week. It's consistant.

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere  thank you - I wish Google would publish details like 72 hours or once per week. That way we can point to a reference document.

Comment: As a recommendation, I would deploy Laravel Horizon as a Docker image on Compute Engine. Horizon requires Redis, which is an additional cost for Cloud Run, but can easily be deployed as another container on Compute Engine. Using the correct services will result in a better experience. Trying to force fit one architecture onto another often results in higher costs, wasted time, and reduced user experience.

Comment: My bad, it was on flexible App Engine. Anyway, it's servers managed by Google, you must be resilient to restart and other possible outage. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/how-instances-are-managed